# Using MQTT to send time stamp - to Arduino

Tags: esp8266, mqtt

In previous question in this forum - I asked about updating clock on an ESP8266, using MQTT broker to send a time stamp on demand, in following manner:

1) ESP8266 sends a publish containing the payload :"sync",

2) broker answers in string format ( this part is python )

```
def on_message(self, client, obj, msg):
    self.arrived_msg = msg.payload.decode()
    if self.arrived_msg == "sync":
        a = datetime.datetime.now()
        b = "%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d" % (a.year, a.month, a.day, a.hour, a.minute, a.second, a.microsecond) .  <------ here a string time format is created
        self.client.publish(topic=self.topics[0], payload=b, qos=self.topic_qos)
```

3) on a terminal (MAC OS), subscribed to relevant topic- cant see publish results. which are OK:

```
sync                           <----- ESP sends request
2018,9,18,12,44,18,903242      <----- string answer from broker
```

4) **BUT** when Arduino code get this time stamp:

```
void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
        char incoming_msg[50];
        // ledBlink(30, 5);
        Serial.print("Message arrived [");
        Serial.print(topic);
        Serial.print("] ");
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                Serial.print((char)payload[i]);  <----- print #1
                incoming_msg[i] = (char)payload[i];  <----- generate incoming msg
        }
        Serial.println("");

        if (strcmp(topic,clockTopic)==0) {       <------- detect relvant topic for clock sync
                Serial.print(incoming_msg);  <------ Print #2
        }
```

5) I get this result on serial monitor :

```
Message arrived [HomePi/Dvir/Clock] 2018,9,18,13,48,5,230009 <---- here time stamp is OK , Print #1
2018,9,18,13,48,5,230009$��?O: @ . <----- Print #2
```

EDIT1:

6) I tried adding a null termination in time stamp, but it just added `\0` to time stamp 
Appreciate any help

Guy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to set the terminating zero of the c-ctring `incoming_msg`.

add `incoming_msg[length] = 0;`

Comment: please see my comment in Majenko's answer

Comment: `incoming_msg[length] = 0;`

Comment: got it the first time :)

Comment: OK- it works. Can you please explain why last char does not regarded as a plain 0 ? and regarded as `\0` ?

Comment: the 0 is valid only in memory as a terminator for the c-string. it is not valid for transport over a network. you get the `payload` bytes and the `length`. you convert the `payload` to a string of length `length` so you must set the terminating zero at the right position of the char array

Answer (score 1):

In C a string is "null terminated".  That means that the very last character of every string *must* be character 0 (or NULL).

You need to ensure that you add that NULL character to the end of your `incoming_msg` string to terminate it, or force the entire string to be cleared to NULLs before you populate it.

The simplest way is to zero the string:

```
bzero(incoming_string, 50);
```

Or you can force a 0 to be appended after each byte is added:

```
incoming_msg[i] = (char)payload[i];
incoming_msg[i+1] = 0;
```

Or just add one at the end:

```
incoming_msg[length] = 0;
```

There's many ways of doing it - as long as you get that NULL in there somehow.

Comment: thank you for your answer, as a matter of fct I tried to send time stamp with null termination ( but with no luck ), I did like :` ('%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%s)` which last parameter was `'\0'`. perhaps I didn;t do it right ? or this is impossible ?

Comment: It's not the sending. It's the copying into your internal array. You discard the null.

Comment: OK, what is the pupose of adding `0` every loop ( as you wrote ) ?

Comment: It's just one of the many ways of ensuring that there is a null after the last character.